# Regresar al mismo punto de la página de la que salgo cuando le doy a "atrás"

Tags: javascript, html5

¿Cómo puedo regresar al mismo punto en el que estoy cuando le doy a un vínculo en una página del mismo sitio web y luego le doy a atrás o volver?

Caso práctico:

En `www.micasa.es` tengo un listado de inmuebles con miles de resultados en una búsqueda y si entro en uno de los pisos anunciados, luego ¿Como puedo volver al mismo punto del listado del que he salido?

Actualmente en el portal `micasa.es` tenemos un listado continuo que se va recargando según se hace scroll y como tenemos ese problema (De como volver al mismo punto del listado cuando vemos un anuncio y luego queremos volver) lo que estamos haciendo en abrir la ficha del inmueble que queremos ver en una ventana nueva, pero eso no es un buen sistema, le llena de pestañas la pantalla del navegador al usuario y cuando quiere volver a donde estaba, no hay botón de atrás y no sabe cual de las pestañas que tiene abiertas es la de los resultados.

Es un poco lioso explicarlo por escrito, pero creo que me he explicado más o menos.

Si podeis ayudarnos, os lo agradecería.

Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

> En www.micasa.es tengo un listado de inmuebles con miles de resultados en una búsqueda y si entro en uno de los pisos anunciados, luego ¿Como puedo volver al mismo punto del listado del que he salido?

Necesitas guardar las coordenadas antes de salir de la página. Puedes guardar las coordenadas en una cookie o en `sessionStorage` para ser más práticos.

Por ejemplo:

```
function saveCoords (e) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("coords", JSON.stringify({
    y: window.scrollY,
    x: window.scrollX
  }));
}

function posicionate () {
  var coords = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("coords"));
  if (coords) {
    window.scrollTo(coords.x, coords.y);
  }
}
```

El método `posicionate` debe ejecutarse al cargar el `body` (`<body onload="posicionate()>`) y la función `saveCoords` debe ejecutarse al hacer click en el link. Internamente, se guardarán las coordenadas del scrollbar en un objeto serializado para que se guarde en el `sessionStorage` y, al cargar el body se obtendrán éstas coordenadas para moverse a donde el usuario se ha quedado.

Answer (score 1):

No es la respuesta exacta a lo que preguntaste pero creo que si quieres abrir una ficha así como dices y luego al cerrarla continuar donde estabas te conviene usar un modal (es muy buena opción ya que al hacer click te abrirá una especie de popup muy elegante y la puedes cerrar y continuar con la navegación)
Si usas boostrapp aqui tienes un ejemplo http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/
Pero lo puedes hacer con javascript tambien.
Saludos